# RegEx to parse javascript object data

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

Within a string of HTML I need to parse out values from a Javascript object. The javascript is always the same as shown below so I need parse so I need to parse the values "Ariat" and "Mens>Footwear>Cowboy Boots>Square Toe" for example between the double quotes. I'm thinking regex is probably the way to go but I've never used it before so I'm hoping to get some guidance on the right way to do this? Maybe a regex example or should I not use regex and go a different direction?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
dataLayer=[{
"conversionType": "Viewed Product",
"conversionAttributes": [

{
"brand_name": "Ariat",
"id": 2464833,
"category" : "Mens>Footwear>Cowboy Boots>Square Toe",
"image": "http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aayu_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-co-master-catalog/default/dwec67444c/images/productimages/237083_90751-mens-rambler-boot-wicker_large.jpg",
"name": "Mens Rambler Square Toe Boot",
"msrp": "159.95",
"price": "149.95",
"sku": "ARIAT-MRamblerSqToe",
"parentSku" :"ARIAT-MRamblerSqToe",
"vendor": "Ariat"
}
]
}];
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Darin, If I understand you correctly, you have a HTML string, which you want to pull a JSON encoded data set from?  The reason I ask is this sound like a simple matter of finding the `script` tag, pulling everything out, and running it through a JSON decoder.  Is this the case, or is the issue more complex?

Comment: Use a JSON parser and don't try to write a raw regex.

Comment: Also, what language are you trying to parse the JSON in?  C# or JavaScript?

Comment: Generally you don't want to load json data from a script tag. It's better to use an http request of some kind. And it can be parsed in JavaScript easier if it is the result of an http request. And your data is being assigned to the variable dataLayer so you don't need to parse anything in any other script you can access it through the dataLayer variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("\"((?:\\\"|[^\"])+)\" *: *\"((?:\\\"|[^\"])+)\");

var matches = pattern.Matches(data);

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    var varName = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var value = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

The pattern basically says: Find open quote then any number of either \" or " followed by close quote. then zero or more spaces, a colon, zero or more spaces and then the same quote pattern again.